# Converting VBA project written in MS Access to ANY modern language

Tags: c#, .net, vba, visual-studio, ms-access

Okay, I know that this is a super weird question and there probably is not an answer other than simply rewriting the entire application. However, I recently took on a project for a client that has a MASSIVE project written inside of Access 2007 with Visual Basic for Applications and some VB6. In order to help them my first plan was to just modernize everything they have. The application runs on XP and I was hoping that I could at least move the project files and forms (automatically) to any type of .net project inside of Visual Studio. I've never used any of the Microsoft developer tools and after a couple days of digging around on the internet, most converters don't actually seem to work. There doesn't seem to be any sort of "best practice" way to bring an old VB project to a more modern developer environment. If rewriting everything is really the only option that's fine I was just hoping that one of you very smart people knew of a way that I could at least get most of the code/forms into a newer environment. If I can just open the project in an older version of Visual Basic that works too (their system has access to every major version since 2008) Thanks in advance!

I am also totally open to porting the project into any other language if there is a better tool that works for say Python, Java, C (any iteration of C), etc.

EDIT: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." – Scott Craner, Steve, Erik von Asmuth, Kostas K., braX

So in response to this, I have attempted to rebuild the project inside of visual studio 2008 and then using the built-in converter bring the code from VBA to VB6 which (for the most part) worked. From there I could save the project and open it in visual studio 2010 once again using the built-in converter to take the code from VB6 to VB.Net. However, this is where the "success" stops. Essentially the project cannot be opened in any newer version of visual studio (attempted with 2012, 2015, and 2017) I was simply hoping that ANYONE would have any ideas on how else I could go about moving this project into Visual Studio or rebuilding it in another language. I understand that the question is not super relevant considering the software I am talking about updating is over 10 years old and some of it even older. Thanks for your responses as I think that it is probably time to evaluate the cost/time involved in a complete rewrite.

Comment: I can understand your pain, (been there myself) but your question is simply off-topic or too broad. And if you really need an opinion, well. rewrite everything.

Comment: Yes, this will be painful.  It will be a total re-write.  I've had to do this for an app that started as Access (ugh) in the late 90's.  It was moved to VB6 with the database in sql server. In the 2012 time frame we needed to move to WIN7/10 which required a re-write as the third party ActiveX controls used were no longer supported.  Definitely a very painful process.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I think at this time it is probably best to recommend a rewrite and see what the client wants to do from there. Y'all are the best!

Comment: Does the client actually want a complete rewrite? Or just some changes that could easily be done in the existing Access application? -- You most probably have seen this, but I'll link it just in case: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"...there probably is not an answer other than simply rewriting the entire application."

I had a similar issue a couple of years ago with a legacy application built on an Access97 database.

There is no quick fix.  You will spend more time trying to beat the existing code into a new form than it is worth.  Use the old code as a guide for structure, but start from scratch.

Comment: This is probably the direction I will take. Sorry, you were awesome enough to respond even though you were inevitably going to be downvoted. I appreciate the response and advice!